# Simple Corona SDK App - Touch Event

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am new to Lua and am currently working on a project called Red VS Blue. It is basically for two teams, red team and blue team, and it functions as a scoreboard. If I click the left side, red gets 1 point. If I click the blue side, blue gets one point. The screen resolution is 320 x 480, but it widens according to the device. 
Here is a screenshot:
http://i40.tinypic.com/5lqosk.jpg

this is my code:

```
display.setStatusBar(display.HiddenStatusBar);
local redscore = 0
local bluescore = 0
local background = display.newImage("images/background.png");
local redc = display.newImage("images/redc.png", 0, 0);
local bluec = display.newImage("images/bluec.png", 240, 0);
local redtext = display.newText(redscore, 55, 100, native.systemFont, 32*4);
local bluetext = display.newText(bluescore , 290, 100, native.systemFont, 32*4);

local function redt( event )
    redscore = redscore + 1;
    return true
end
redc:addEventListener( "tap", redt )

local function bluet( event )
    bluescore = bluescore + 1;
    return true
end
bluec:addEventListener( "tap", bluet )
```

redc and bluec are blank pictures that act as sensors

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: well, the touch function doesn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to scale the picture to always fit perfectly the half of the screen, do this:

```
--[[
    Take half the width of the device and adjust for larger screens, dividing by
    the current width of the picture to produce the value it needs to be scaled
    by to fit
]]
local wScale = ((display.layoutWidth/2) - display.screenOriginX) / redc.contentWidth

--Do the same for the height
local hScale = ((display.layoutHeight/2) - display.screenOriginY) / redc.contentHeight

--Scale the image
redc:scale(wScale,hScale)

--[[
    Position the image. Since the default is a central reference point, you take half of              
    the image's width/height and add the adjustment for larger screens
]]
redc.x = (redc.contentWidth/2) + display.screenOriginX
redc.y = (redc.contentHeight/2) + display.screenOriginY
```

And to make the scoreboard update when the box is touched, structure your event listener as follows:

```
local function redt( event )
    redscore = redscore + 1;
    redtext.text = tostring(redscore)
    return true
end
redc:addEventListener( "tap", redt )
```

Repeat for the blue box. Anything else you wanted to do with it?

Comment: Thanks you so much or the answer! It works now. Just an afterthought, usually when you code lua or any other language, do you comment, or was it just to teach me? like this:     --this is a comment

Comment: No problem, Corona can be a bit of a bugger sometimes - I kid you not, I've solved a few "this object is nil" bugs simply by printing out a string representation of the object using `print(tostring(object))`. It baffles me to this day.

It is **always** best practice to comment your code, firstly because if you come back to it later you can sometimes forget the workarounds or quick fixes you've done. Secondly, because everyone codes in a different way and so for someone else to view/help edit your code without comments would be extremely difficult

Comment: Note: in lua

`--This is a single line comment`
`--[[ This is a multi-line comment ]]`

As you can see from my answer above